# How to Multiline Logstash for Date lines?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

My log contains some lines that don't start with dates I'd like to multiline to previous lines that did contain dates. Except using the pattern '^%{YEAR}' with negate: true and previous does not work (i.e. makes no difference if the stdin section is there or not and treats each as a separate line).

What is the config to get this working? Using the same pattern I've also tried negate false, and after as well as different combinations also in the yml.

```
2019/02/13  10:46:14.9282   SomeStuff
ErrorLine1
ErrorLine2
ErrorLine3
etc.
2019/02/13  10:46:14.9282   OtherStuff
```

```
2019/02/13  10:46:14.9282   SomeStuff ErrorLine1 ErrorLine2 ErrorLine3 etc.
2019/02/13  10:46:14.9282   OtherStuff
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }

  stdin {
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
      }
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
     stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working at all or is it ignoring the last line on your example? I've just tested your configuration and it works, but the last line is ignored because it is not a multiline event, the codec needs a non matching line to send the event.

Comment: Not working at all and not sure why...unfortunately.

Comment: What Logstash version are you using? Do you have any filters and what is your output? Using that configuration and with an output to a file I've got this: 
`{"host":"elk","tags":["multiline"],"message":"2019/02/13  10:46:14.9282   SomeStuff\nErrorLine1\nErrorLine2\nErrorLine3\netc.","@timestamp":"2019-02-24T19:07:05.811Z","@version":"1"}`

Comment: Logstash 6.3.0. I am abstracting for a work project but the output is the same as if the stdin portion was not there at all. filter shouldn't affect the pre-processing of the input though? I removed the filter as a test anyway and still the same result. When I saw it worked for you indeed I turned my attention to the logstash version, still researching if that is related here.

Comment: The multiline codec version on Logstash 6.3.0 is the same as the last version of Logstash, should not be the problem. If you have any filters, it affects the output, can you update your question with your full pipeline? The input, filter and output blocks.

Comment: Sure, it is added.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the configuration, but why the beats input? It shouldn't interfere in the pipeline, but there is no need for it if you are testing with the stdin input. Also, instead of `%{YEAR}` you could test using a a regex expression, this one works for your case `pattern => "^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}". The codec configuration is correct since it worked when I replicated it, I think that the problem is in how you are passing the data to Logstash.